# Error importing using Content Porter 2009 SP1

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009, schema, metadata

I am facing the following error while importing the content. Even after syncing the Schema, the issue still persists.

I am using Content Porter 2009 SP1.

**I also came to know that Metadata field has been added recently in export environment. After Schema change the Component XMLs are not updated. If I can update the Components of that Schema that will do I guess.**

```
Error details:
        (TCMDAL::ExecuteRequest:Content Manager returned an error)  
        (Cause=true)  Unable to find http://website/schemas/sdltridion:Metadata.
        (Cause=false)  Unable to save Component (tcm:0-0-0).
        (Callstack)  Request.SaveItem - Component.Save - XMLState.Save -
Tridion.ContentManager.BLFacade.ContentManagement.VersionedItemFacade.CreateAndCheckIn(UserContext,String,Boolean) -
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save() -
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.Save(Boolean) -
Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.Save(SaveEventArgs) -
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs) -
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.VersionedItem.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs) -
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.OnSaving(SaveEventArgs) -
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.ValidateXml() -
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.RepositoryLocalObject.ValidateXml() -
Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.ValidateXml(Schema,XmlElement,Repository) -
Tridion.ContentManager.ContentManagement.Component.AssertValidRootContentElements(XmlSchemaSet,String) -
Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.AssertValidRootContentElement(XmlElement,XmlSchemaSet,XmlQualifiedName)
        (TCMDAL::Communications::CheckResponseForErrors)  Errors encountered during check of response
        (TCMDAL::Communications::ExecuteRequest)  Error while executing request
        (TCMDAL::TCMItem:Create)  Error while creating item based on given XML
```

Comment: Did you export and import the schema as well as the component? The error suggests that the component is not valid against the schema that is currently in the target environment.

Comment: Can you perhaps edit your question and add the XML of the Component and the XSD of the Schema you are trying to import?

Comment: @Quirjin. I have done schema export and import as well.

Comment: Did you check whether the Metadata schema has also been imported (or already available) on the target server?

Comment: @PankajGaur. I just checked the component XML of the item being exported. It has empty metadata element. Earlier metadata field was not there in schema, later it was added. Now I want to reflect it in all components.

Comment: @BartKoopman. The metadata field has been added recently but it has not reflected in all components.

Comment: If you have mandatory (metadata) fields which are not in the Component XML, then you can NEVER import this. You will have to change the Schema to contain non mandatory fields or update all your Components with values for the mandatory fields.

Comment: @BartKoopman. There are no mandatory fields in metadata schema. Is there any way that I can update all components based out of this schema.

Comment: @Quirijn. I have updated the question. can you check.

Comment: @Patan It seems a straightforward case of unsynchronized components then. Following Jaime's recipe below, or manually opening and closing the components on the source system should solve it.

Comment: @Quirijn. there are many components I am going to run this program.

Comment: You can also use [Content Porter itself to synchronize components into the same environment](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/sdl-content-porters-synchronization-option). Synchronizing is limited to field moves, removed fields, and new fields. Anything else needs some manual (open then save & close in the CME) or programmatic changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the content you are migrating is not in sync with the Schema it is based on. I would do a where used in the Schema the component is based on and check-out/check-in all the components to sync them up with the latest version of the schema. If you have event system or workflow, I recommend you disable them before going through this process.

If you have a lot of components to synchronize you can use this code snippet:

```
try
        {
            string schemaUri = "YOUR_SCHEMA_URI";

            //Open the Core Service Session
            this.OpenSession();                
            UsingItemsFilterData filter = new UsingItemsFilterData();
            filter.ItemTypes = new ItemType[] { ItemType.Component };
            filter.IncludedVersions = VersionCondition.OnlyLatestVersions;


            //session is the Core Service Client
            XElement result = session.GetListXml(schemaUri.ToString(), filter);

            foreach (XElement element in result.Elements()) {
                String componentId = element.Attribute("ID").Value;
                ComponentData c = session.Read(componentId, new ReadOptions()) as ComponentData;
                if (!c.LockInfo.LockType.Value.HasFlag(LockType.CheckedOut))
                {
                    session.CheckOut(componentId, true, new ReadOptions());                        
                }
                session.CheckIn(componentId, new ReadOptions());
            }



        }
        catch (Exception Exception)
        {
            Console.Write(Exception.Message);
        }
        finally {
            //Close the Core Service Session               
            this.CloseSession();
        }
```

By checking out/in  the Components you are kind of synchronizing them, as long as you didn' modified the schema and you added a mandatory field, in which case you'll have to give it a default value when running the process.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am getting syntax error at c.LockInfo.LockType.Value.HasFlag

Comment: Forgot to mention, this code is 2013... and the referenced assembly for core service is: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.dll within the TRIDION_HOME\bin\client folder.

Comment: How much does a check in/out do? Component synchronizing is usually for new fields, field moves, new mandatory fields, and namespace changes.

Comment: Alvin, check out/in, does a check out and then a check in :) So basically it acts like changing something in the component without changing it, meaning that at check in time it will validate with the new schema. So if you removed a field, the check in operation will remove the component xml associated to that field (both content and metadata). However as I mention in my answer, if the schema modification is more intrusive (like adding a mandatory field) you will need: 1 check out, 2 set a value on the field and 3, a check in to "apply" the component xml changes.